# Kotlin/Native to C dylib : How to access class members in a instance object which returned by a method?

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to learn Kotlin/Native C interop

I exported some Kotlin classes as C dynamic Lib and succeeded in access methods with primitive return types

But When trying to access class members in a instance object which returned by a method, the object contains something named as `pinned`

Code sample:

```
@Serializable
data class Persons (
    val results: Array<Result>,
    val info: Info
)

class RandomUserApiJS {

    fun getPersonsDirect() : Persons {
       return runBlocking {
           RandomUserApi().getPersons()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when using them in C codeblocks,

[image: c_block]

In this image, note that the persons obj only showing a field named `pinned` and no other member functions found.

Since I don't know that much in C/C++ and can't investigate further.

Please help me to understand to access instance members of Kotlin Class in exported C lib?

Header file for ref:
https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/a0b9007376084fa8b213b022b58f9886

Comment: can you provide a sample for kotlin

Comment: @bppleman updated all files in this Gist . please check. Thanks in advance https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/a0b9007376084fa8b213b022b58f9886

Comment: @bppleman need to scroll a bit down to get all kotlin files in the above gist

Answer (score 1):

for your gist

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/a0b9007376084fa8b213b022b58f9886

I modified the following:

```kotlin
// I comment this annotation
// @Serializable
data class Persons(
    val results: List<Result>,
    val info: Info,
    /**
     * the Result's properties too many
     * I will use a simple data class for this example
     * how to get c array from Persons (also suitable any iterable)
     */
    val testList: List<Simple>,
) {
    public fun toJson() = Json.encodeToString(this)

    companion object {
        public fun fromJson(json: String) = Json.decodeFromString<Persons>(json)
    }

    val arena = Arena()
    fun getTestListForC(size: CPointer<IntVar>): CPointer<COpaquePointerVar> {
        size.pointed.value = testList.size
        return arena.allocArray<COpaquePointerVar>(testList.size) {
            this.value = StableRef.create(testList[it]).asCPointer()
        }
    }

    fun free() {
        arena.clear()
    }
}

/**
 * kotlin <-> c bridge is primitive type
 * like int <-> Int
 * like char* <-> String
 * so the Simple class has two primitive properties
 */
data class Simple(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
)
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libnative_api.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    libnative_ExportedSymbols* lib = libnative_symbols();
    libnative_kref_MathNative mn = lib->kotlin.root.MathNative.MathNative();
    const char *a = lib->kotlin.root.MathNative.mul(mn,5,6); // working
    printf ("Math Resullt %s\n",a);

    libnative_kref_RandomUserApiJS pr = lib->kotlin.root.RandomUserApiJS.RandomUserApiJS();
    libnative_kref_Persons persons = lib->kotlin.root.RandomUserApiJS.getPersonsDirect(pr);

    // when accessing above persons obj, only a field 'pinned' availabe, nothing else
    int size;
    libnative_kref_Simple* list = (libnative_kref_Simple *)lib->kotlin.root.Persons.getTestListForC(persons, &size);
    printf("size = %d\n", size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        const char *name = lib->kotlin.root.Simple.get_name(list[i]);
        int age = lib->kotlin.root.Simple.get_age(list[i]);
        printf("%s\t%d\n", name, age);
    }
    lib->kotlin.root.Persons.free(persons);
    return 0;
}
```

```
// for output
Math Resullt The answer is 30
size = 3
name1   1
name2   2
name3   3
```

But I don't think calling kotlin lib through C is a good behavior, because kotlin native is not focused on improving performance for now, in my opinion, all functions that can be implemented with kotlin native can find solutions implemented in pure c, So I'm more focused on how to access the c lib from kotlin. Of course, it's a good solution if you absolutely need to access klib from c, but I'm still not very satisfied with it, then I may create a github template to better solve kotlin-interop from c.But that's not the point of this answer.

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to run it I get : Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_libnative_symbols", referenced from:
      _main in sam-fdee5f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: I am using mac m2

Comment: You need at least to get Math Result by running it without adding additional code. This is your original code, and then try to modify it according to the above. This code does not introduce additional dependencies. It also runs on my mac m1.  Are you not importing kotlin.cinterop.* correctly

Comment: I suddenly get this error. Even trying CLion IDE. Still getting this error https://imgur.com/a/jlGhBRT

Comment: It doesn't matter, what you need is basic knowledge related to cmake try search add_library target_link_library

Comment: Yeah I added in cmake like this find_library(libnative libnative.dylib PATHS /Users/rageshantonyd/CLionProjects/c_kotln) ↵↵
             target_link_libraries(c_kotln ${libnative})

Comment: But still get that error

Comment: Here is a very complete case I created recently, I don't want to break the community norm and generate self-marketing, but if you can't get started with cmake, maybe this link can help you
[Kotlin/Native as a dynamic library — tutorial](https://medium.com/@bppleman/kotlin-native-as-a-dynamic-library-tutorial-c1b844a401bc)

Comment: My dear friend. Thanks very much for your well detailed tutorial. I successfully executed  upto .10 now.

Comment: Why I am trying this is, my company asked me to conduct a crash course on KMM for my team since I have 6 months experience in KMM. Building for Android,iOS,JS and JVM is not a problem for me. But this Native part, it's a nightmare before since I have no intro to any of this .. cmake, lib linking etc. That's why I rolling here in Stackoverflow

Comment: You made my day very easier and also this tutorial is very useful for my colleagues and even my friends. Thanks for your care by writing a dedicated tutorial on this . I shall this to everyone . . Get back to you soon